# Disable (JetBrains) code inspections for an entire project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, rider, code-inspection

I'd like to disable code inspections for certain projects (like tests or quick-n-dirty proof-of-concept ones).

The section [Suppressing code inspections in specific scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#suppress) goes only up to the file level by suggesting this:

> **Inspection [name of inspection] | Disable once with comment | Disable all inspection in file** - this option inserts a single comment - **`ReSharper disable All`** in the beginning of the file. This comment suppresses all inspections the file.

---

What would I have to do to go even further and do the same but for an **entire project**?

This means:

- not a solution
- not a file
- not a method
- not entirely
- not roslyn-analyzers
- **but** just a single project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it, but I think this is the closest option you can try:

[image]

It's also explained in [Jetbrains' website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#excluding-frozen-projects-from-indexing).

Comment: The docs for that feature are [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#excluding-frozen-projects-from-indexing) - _"The ignored projects will not be indexed by ReSharper, meaning that no ReSharper features — e.g. code analysis, refactorings, code generation — will be available in those projects."_