# How do I disable a specific Resharper inspection across an entire project?

Tags: resharper

Resharper alerts me about public functions that are never accessed. This is useful in most areas in my code, but I have a project that contains classes that function as a public API (actually Hot-Chocolate GraphAPI functions), so, naturally, there are no calls to them elsewhere in the code. I don't need Resharper to tell me about them.

I know it's possible to disable these kinds of warnings per file by including a comment. I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this warning across an entire project.

N.B. I don't want to disable Resharper *itself* in this project (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869232/498403)). Resharper is still providing value to me and it's just this specific warning that I want to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link provided (thanks @IgorAkhmetov) I created an `.editorSettings` file in the scope I wanted (the root of the single project) with the following contents:

```
resharper_unused_member_global_highlighting = none
resharper_class_never_instantiated_global_highlighting = none
```

Outcome: Resharper stopped telling me about unused public members, or uninstantiated public classes, in *that project only*. It carries on telling me about those problems in the rest of my codebase.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper's help lists [various ways](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#change_severity) to disable a specific inspection. You can disable a specific inspection in a scope either using an .editorconfig file, or with a ReSharper settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Option "Solution-wide inspections" can be turned off in project's properties:
[image]

Comment: I still want _other_ inspections to apply in this project as well.

Comment: "Solution-Wide Inspections" option in projects properties affects only global usage inspections like "non-private member is never used", "non-private class is never instantiated" and others that requires knowledge about symbols usage in other files and projects.